# Missing XeLateX when trying to use NBconvert (to PDF) on Windows

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, miktex, xelatex, nbconvert

Jupyter's default export to PDF, like the command-line NBconvert tool, are telling me that I can't convert my notebook to PDF because the PDF conversion goes via `xelatex`. The error message refers me to [this help page](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex), so I installed MiKTeX. I have a `xelatex` folder in `AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex`, but I'm not sure what exactly I should add to my PATH.

If it's helpful, here is some of the code in nbconvert's pdf.py:

```
def run_latex(self, filename):
    """Run xelatex self.latex_count times."""

    def log_error(command, out):
        self.log.critical(u"%s failed: %s\n%s", command[0], command, out)

    return self.run_command(self.latex_command, filename,
        self.latex_count, log_error)
```

Comment: Can you run xelatex from the command prompt at all?

Comment: Should there be an executable? What file type is it?

Comment: Try running the command prompt as administrator. Then type in "xelatex" and hit enter. Do you get something like "xelatex: warning: running with administrator privileges" back?
Also - do you have "xelatex.exe" in `AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\bin\x64` (or `x86` if you're on 32 bit)?

Comment: 1) Yes, I got that. 2) Yes, found it! (Path is slightly different, it's `...MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64`.) Should I add this folder to my PATH?

Comment: Hmm. If you got  "xelatex: warning: running with administrator privileges" back, it should have already been added to PATH. Add it if it isn't already there...

Comment: Weird. It doesn't seem to be dependent on the notebook either. I added a comment on [this issue thread](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/799).

Comment: Never mind - rebooting my machine solved it. Thanks for your help!